# How to export this code and insert on an existing page - React Beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I would like to export this code and import it on another page. How can I do this with React? So on the page where I want to have the slideshow, all I have to do is insert "import slider from "slideshow";"?

Slideshow:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Gallery, GalleryImage } from "react-gesture-gallery";

const images = [
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559666126-84f389727b9a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1356&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557389352-e721da78ad9f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553969420-fb915228af51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550596334-7bb40a71b6bc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550640964-4775934de4af?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"
];

function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (index === 4) {
        setIndex(0);
      } else {
        setIndex(prev => prev + 1);
      }
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <Gallery
      style={{
        background: "black",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw"
      }}
      index={index}
      onRequestChange={i => {
        setIndex(i);
      }}
    >
      {images.map(image => (
        <GalleryImage objectFit="contain" key={image} src={image} />
      ))}
    </Gallery>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow need to have the code *in the question itself* as a [mcve]. Take a look at [ask].

Comment: @Herohtar I edited my post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an export statement at the bottom of the code you wish to export.

E.g

```
   Export default App;
```

Then you will need an import statement at the top of the code you wish to import to.

E.g.

```
    import App from "./app.js";
```

If you want a better answer you may need to edit your question,and clean it up a little.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I've already made it with the import. Since I already declared App before, I renamed the function to slider. But now I have the problem that he either uses my previous function App OR slider. But it doesn't do both. When I import the slider into my index.js, it is also grayed out, so it is not available, unfortunately I don't know why.

Comment: I’m fairly amateur myself. However I find it best to keep the name  ‘App’ just for the component I wish to render as it is already set up like that by create-react-app. Maybe you just need to go through and consider renaming your components, remember you will need to change the imports/exports also. And sometimes it’s easier to start fresh and just pull the parts across from your first draft.